# Backbone -> Cannot call method 'remove' of undefined

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

My app is built using backbone. I run into problems when trying to use destroy() on a model, this is the error stack I get in chrome:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'remove' of undefined backbone-min.js:34
f.extend.remove backbone-min.js:34
g.Events.trigger backbone-min.js:9
f.extend.destroy.d backbone-min.js:14
f.extend.destroy backbone-min.js:14
Backbone.Model.extend.remove ticketModel.js:21
Backbone.View.extend.deleteTicket ticketListView.js:44
b.each.b.forEach underscore-min.js:11
Backbone.View.extend.deleteTicketTickets ticketListView.js:49
f.event.dispatch jquery-1.7.2.min.js:3
f.event.add.h.handle.i
```

Any idea what this could be?

The code causing the error was literally just:

```
model.destroy();
```

model does certainly contain a model as a `console.log(model)` logs the object to the console as it should.

Here's the model definition:

```
define([
    'apiEndpoint'
    ],function(apiEndpoint) {
    var TicketModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        url: apiEndpoint.url,

        isTicket : function(){
            return ( this.type === 'ticket') ? true : false;
        },

        isTask : function(){
            return ( this.type === 'task') ? true : false;
        },

        //Tells you if the view is selected for bulk actions
        defaults : {
            isSelected: false
        },

        remove : function(){
            this.destroy({success: function(){
                console.log('success');
            }});
        }

    });
    return TicketModel;
});
```

Comment: Add the relevant code to your question

Comment: did that. hope that makes it clearer

Comment: I mean the model definition code

Comment: Are you calling `something.remove()` anywhere in your code related to this? The only place backbone would do that is in the `remove` view method doing: `this.$el.remove()` Can you verify that `relatedView.$el` is in fact not `undefined` just before you call `.destroy`?

Comment: Nothing in what you posted seems to cause that error, see http://jsfiddle.net/SFvuM/ . Maybe a method bound to a sync event or more probably to a destroy event?

Comment: the model that I'm trying to destroy is passed by filtering a collection and it's logged as 'child'. Might that be an issue?

Comment: Could be, Backbone tries to remove a destroyed model from its parent collection. Could you add the relevant code? And modify my Fiddle if you can and reproduce your issue?

Comment: I can't seem to be able to replicate it: http://jsfiddle.net/SFvuM/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view Why are you calling `model.destroy();`? I think that you must call `model.remove();` because is your custom method to destroy.

Looks like in your View you are calling `model.destroy()` and later `model.remove`, but because you already destroyed your model, now you are trying to call a remove method of undefined object.

Comment: I'm not sure why you get the idea that I'm calling model.destroy in my view.

Comment: You wrote this: "The code causing the error was literally just:

model.destroy();"

Comment: well, I just described what wasn't working, I never said I've used it in a view. But anyway, I'm not calling it twice if that answers your question. The whole thing seems unproducable, I'm now replicating the whole infrastructure to see what the problem is

Comment: I was assuming... because you pasted the error stack but not the code of the lines, just one line supposed to be the caller. Looks like the issue is on these lines, Backbone.Model.extend.remove ticketModel.js:21
Backbone.View.extend.deleteTicket ticketListView.js:44, please paste those lines with context and surely we could find the issue. ;)